# Android: subscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList() gives null, although SIM is present

Tags: android, kotlin, telephonymanager

Using SubscriptionManager for fetching sim details, but for few users subscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList() is returning null(READ_PHONE_STATE permission is granted), even if sim is present in the device.

```
val subscriptionManager: SubscriptionManager = (SubscriptionManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE);
val subscriptionInfos = subscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();
```

Is there any other way to fetch sim details?

Comment: I'm having the same error. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @AxesGrinds nope

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: @DipendraSharma not yet

Comment: @IshitaGarg, did you find any solution for this?

Comment: I request Permission 'android.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS' which helps in Android 12.